# Read log file from bz2 file in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, compression, osx-lion, bzip2

I would like to read the contents of a logfile that has been rotated to a bz2 file. How can I do this while using as little memory as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out using these scripts: 
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BzipValueTransformer &
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataPlusBzip

What you need to do is include the `libbz2.a` which I found in `/opt/local/lib/libbz2.a` since I installed `bzip2` using macports. I draged the file into my project and wrote the code:

```
- (void)bunzip
{
    NSString *path = @"/var/log/kernel.log.1.bz2";

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSString *dataString = [[Bzip2ValueTransformer alloc] transformedValue:data];

    NSLog(@"Data: %@", dataString);
}
```

Result:

```
Dec 16 23:26:58 Paul-Peelens-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP
Dec 16 23:26:58 Paul-Peelens-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on en1
Dec 16 23:26:58 Paul-Peelens-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 32:7b:98:82:9d:7f
Dec 16 23:30:10 paul-peelens-macbook-pro newsyslog[13862]: logfile turned over due to size>1000K
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use NSTask or [my own PRHTask](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/prhtask/) to open a [bunzip2](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bunzip2.1.html) process with its standard input connected to the bzip2 file, and its standard output set to a pipe. Use NSFileHandle's asynchronous reading or GCD's `dispatch_source` to read from that pipe in the background as data comes in.